# FIlling a 2D array with random integers java

Tags: java, random

I am trying to create an nxn array full of random integers between 1 and 10.  When I try to print it out, I am getting an odd number of integers not filling an array, and never up to the correct number of integers (for instance, a supposed 5x5 array is returning 17 integers).  Code snippet follows, assume all variable are declared correctly unless contained in here and java.util.Random is imported.

```
if (choice==1){
     Random rand = new Random();
     System.out.println("Please input a power n for (nxn array) between 1-6");
     int power = kb.nextInt();
     int[][] randMatrix = new int[power-1][power-1];
     if (power < 1 || power > 6){
        System.out.println("Invalid power");
     }else{
        for (i=0; i<randMatrix.length; i++){
           for (j=0; j<randMatrix.length; j++){
              randMatrix[i][j] = rand.nextInt(9);
           }
        }for (i=0; i<randMatrix.length; i++){
           for (j=0; j<randMatrix.length; j++){
              System.out.println(randMatrix[i][j]);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Your j loops are using the wrong length in the conditional.

Comment: Try for (j=0; j<randMatrix[i].length; j++)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't print 17 integers, it prints 16. This is because 16 is 4 * 4 and you should have done

```
new int[power][power]
```

rather than

```
new int[power-1][power-1]
```

The comments are also correct that it should be

```
for (j = 0; j < randMatrix[i].length; j++)
```

but this does not explain your problem, as the array is square.